# Read file line by line and do regex validation

Tags: java, regex, validation, delimiter

What is the proper way for validating weather the imported text file matches with this block of text, line by line by Regex

- Title: Effort required for coding
- YLabel: Effort
- XLabel: Lines
- XStart: 0
- XInterval: 2500
- 0, 100, 200, 400, 700, 1024

for example: I tried with this regex syntax to check the first line i.e (Title: Effort required for coding) but the expression is not correct

```
 public Boolean fileValidation(String input){
    boolean bool = input.matches("^Title(?=.*:) [a-zA-Z]");
    
    
     if(bool){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Valid File", "Valid", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
     }else{
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid File", "Invalid", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
     }
     return bool;
    
}
```

This is my code for reading selected text file line by line

```
try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        
        String info = "";
        
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            
            info += scan.nextLine() + "\n";
            readtxt.setText(info);
            fileValidation(info);
            
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: From my point of view, all lines are valid.

Comment: What exactly has to be validated? What matches or not? What did you try?

Comment: `If (bool == true) ...else if (bool == false) ` at least this can be written in better way.

Comment: I'm new to programming

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "Title: Effort required for coding";

System.out.println(s.matches("^Title(?=.*:): [a-zA-Z ]+"));
```

Blank and + for the rest of the string were missing.